# Error on cassandra-3.11.3-1.noarch centos7

Tags: replication, cassandra, centos, distributed-databases, centos-7

I've a cluster consisting of 5 cassandra nodes. The cassandra version used is

```
cassandra-3.11.3-1.noarch
```

The `keyspace` strategy and is defined as follows:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace 
    WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '2'}  
    AND durable_writes = true;
```

Now running queries on the cluster, the following issue occurs:

> ```
> ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] 
> message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" 
> info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'failures': 1} 
> info={'failures': None, 'consistency': 'Not Set', 'required_responses': None, 'received_responses': None}
> ```

Does anyone know what is causing this? If more information needed to better debug this problem, please let me know!

**UPDATE 1**

```
root# awk '!/#/' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties

dc=datacenter1
rack=rack1
```

Comment: Can you show content of the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` ? What query is executed?

Comment: @AlexOtt  See update.  I also set the `tracing`  to `on`